# Trigger a function call on click of button "open" of upload file dialog

Tags: angularjs

On click of "Import CSV" button, i want to open a "Open file dialog explorer" and on selecting a file and click on open in the explorer, it should trigger a function call(function addCSVFile()). How do i achieve this?

My .js looks like below:

```
<input type="button" class="btn-import" id="loadFileXml"  value="Import CSV"
       onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();"/>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

onchange and ng-change i have tried. but both are not working. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know angular js but this simple jquery should work if you don't mind using it...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></scipt>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#file").on('change',function(){
        //do whatever you want
      });
});
</script>
```

You can also use for attribute of label like this...

```
<label for="file" class="btn-import" id="loadFileXml">Import File</label>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to solve this:

*.html i altered like below

```
<input type="button" class="btn-import" id="loadFileXml" value="Import CSV"
       ng-click="vm.file_changed()"/>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" accept=".csv"
       script-upload="vm.fileToUpload"/>
```

*.js

```
function file_changed() {
    $('#file').click();
}

function onScriptSelect(files) {
    var filename = files[0].name;
}
```